# Using LoDash, how do I integrate a function into a _where method?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have an array of objects that each have a date property.  For some of the objects, the "Date" property is blank.  I want to remove those from my object so that my view doesn't end up with entries containing NaN for the date.

Here is what I have tried:

```
_.where(data, { 'Date': d.Date instanceof Date && isFinite(d) })
```

AND

```
_.where(data, function(d) {
                        return d.Date instanceof Date && isFinite(d.date);
                    });
```

Both return 0 results however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use [`where`](http://lodash.com/docs#where) that "*performs a deep comparison to the given property object*" , but [`filter`](http://lodash.com/docs#filter) that uses a callback.

Comment: D'oh!  Thanks.  I can accept your answer in 6 minutes.